# openssh cannot create directory /home/local/<my username>/.ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, openssh

When I try `ssh [IP]` openssh warns `Could not create directory '/home/local/[my username]/.ssh'`.

I do have an `.ssh` directory, in another path, in my actual home directory, at `/home/[myusername]/.ssh`.

Why is openssh adding a `local` to that home path? That path does not exist. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 my `$HOME` is set properly, i.e. `/home/[my username]`.

I can't find where openssh is configured to even look for that 'local' path. I've grep'ed for `local` under `/etc/ssh/` which did not return anything.

**Update:**

`getent passwd $USER` shows the wrong home path, with the 'local' in the path. Apparently openssh uses the home path as output by that command, instead of the `$HOME` environment variable to find the home directory. I can't just edit `/etc/passwd` as $USER comes from an LDAP. Not sure if my IT department can edit my home path in LDAP, is there a way I can tell openssh what home path to use, i.e. $HOME not `getent passwd $USER`?

Comment: If `getent passwd $USER` shows that your home directory doesn't exist, you have a system configuration problem. You need to talk to your system administrator(s) about fixing it, either by fixing the LDAP data or perhaps by creating `/home/local/username` as a symlink to your actual home directory. It's reasonable for ssh to assume that the system's user information is correct; if it's not looking at `$HOME` there's probably no workaround. Also, this isn't really a programming question; it would probably be better for  [sf].

Comment: I reached out to my IT department. They updated my home directory in LDAP and after a reboot of my local machine, openssh works.

Comment: @mipnw Well done. I have edited the answer to illustrate an LDAP-managed SSH access.

Answer (score 0):

> Apparently openssh uses the home path as output by that command

I use quite often `openssh` with `HOME` set to a different folder than the default one, and it works without any issue.
Check your other environment variables to see if there are other mentions of the wrong path in one of them.

As the OP comments, the issue was in the LDAP managing the account.

It is true you can store ssh keys in LDAP, which allows SSH connection from any server where you are logged on (since your keys are fetched from LDAP)

Example of LDAP schema:

In `/usr/local/lib/ldap/schema/openssh-ltk.ldif`:

```yaml
    dn: cn=openssh-lpk,cn=schema,cn=config
    objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
    cn: openssh-lpk
    olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.24552.500.1.1.1.13 NAME 'sshPublicKey'
        DESC 'MANDATORY: OpenSSH Public key'
        EQUALITY octetStringMatch
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.40 )
    olcObjectClasses: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.24552.500.1.1.2.0 NAME 'ldapPublicKey' SUP top AUXILIARY
        DESC 'MANDATORY: OpenSSH LPK objectclass'
        MAY ( sshPublicKey $ uid )
    )
```